# Multiple Links In QR Code

Tags: barcode, qr-code

I was playing around with a `QR Code` generator for `PHP` today and it got me to wondering. Is there any way to have multiple links within a `QR Code`? Something like the text being:

```
http://www.facebook.com,http://www.yahoo.com
```

or

```
[{"http://www.google.com"}, {"http://www.yahoo.com"}]
```

Nothing even close has come up for me in web searches. I am imagining a process where you would scan the `QR Code` and then choose which link you would like to go to. Anyone have any ideas on this? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no provision in the standard for multiple URLs. Any handling of such would be scanner-specific and non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can put up to 4096 characters in a standard size QR code (some larger sizes support more) but most parsers will only interpret a complete, valid URL and open it in a browser window (which is what it sounds like you want). That's your real sticking point. The QR code itself is agnostic as to the data it's holding.

If you want to write one that could parse multiples like you suggest, I would suggest checking out [Zebra Crossing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), an open source QR code scanner.

Comment: direkt Link to Zebra Crossing is now https://github.com/zxing/zxing since code.google is not active anymore...